# " Errno 13 Permission denied 'bnr_code.csv'"?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have deployed  a Django project on server using apache2 and wsgi, Its showing an error which I probably know that why its coming.

Error:

```
IOError at /
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'bnr_code.csv'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://93.188.167.63:8080/pep_learn/
Django Version: 1.10.8
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'bnr_code.csv'
Exception Location: /home/pep_web/binaryDs/views.py in <module>, line 6
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
```

I have tried some slandered solutions which are available as given bellow:

chmod 777 pep_web/

chmod 771 pep_web/

sudo chown :www-data pep_web/

But nothing is working

This is the file  which uses 'bnr_code.csv'

```
AA = {"A":"1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "C":"0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "D":"0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "E":"0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "F":"0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "G":"0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "H":"0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "I":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "K":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "L":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "M":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "N":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "P":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "Q":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0",
      "R":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0",
      "S":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0",
      "T":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0",
      "V":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0",
      "W":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0",
      "Y":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1"}



line = []
seqs = ["ATTTRY","ATSSRY"]


def bnr(x):
    Des = []
    for n in x:
        Des.append(AA[n.upper()])
    des = ",".join(Des)
    return des

def Des_write(ps):
    f = open("bnr_code.csv",'w')
    for p in ps:
        a  = bnr(p)
        f.write(p+','+a+'\n')
    f.close()


Des_write(seqs)
```

**Please help One can examine the error at http://93.188.167.63:8080/pep_learn/**

Comment: The error at your link (please, don't post links, copy the text into your question) says: `global name 'os' is not defined`.  Seems like you forgot to `import os`.   The link does not show "Permission denied".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a relative path to the file, use an absolute path. This issue is explained in the documentation for mod_wsgi.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory

Calculate the location of the file by doing:

```
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'bnr_code.csv')
```

Comment: I tried but its not working, and throwing same error

Comment: You did change ``open("bnr_code.csv",'w')`` to use ``filename`` instead? Ie., ``open(filename, 'w')``. Put a ``print()`` statement in code to log the value of ``filename`` to verify it is being written where you expect. Check the permissions on that directory.

Comment: Its working now I just deleted and reinstalled  the base folder "pep_web" and again run  "sudo chown :www-data pep_web/", with the recommended change in path and now its working.