# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/home/pep_web/Structure_Descriptor/Input.csv'?

Tags: python, django, apache, django-models, django-templates

I have posted similar problem few days before but that time it was just solved by replacing manual path with the absolute path this time again i stuck with the similar problem and I have tried many thing but nothing is working. How can I resolve this problem

This  is my view which is throwing the error:

```
def Pep_Str_Des(request):
    #return render(request, 'PepStructure/Structure.html', {})


if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Pep_str_Des(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        val = form.cleaned_data['Input_peptide']


        pep_list = []
        for v in val.split(','):
            if len(val.split(',')[0]) <= 17:
                if len(val.split(',')[0]) == len(v):
                    pep_list.append(v) 
                    print v


        df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':pep_list})

        print df
        #file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'Input.csv')
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'Input.csv'), index = False)

        os.environ['Input_file'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'Input.csv')
        os.environ['out_file'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'Out_file.csv') 

        os.environ['cmds'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'Structure_bassed_Descriptor_generation.py')

        os.system("python $cmds -p $Input_file -d $out_file") 



        f_ns = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'strs')+"/*.pdb")

        for f in f_ns:
            os.remove(f)

        f_ns = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'strs')+"/*.sdf")

        for f in f_ns:
            os.remove(f)

        return render(request, 'Structure_Descriptor/Out.html', {'val':val} )


else:
    Input_peptide = 'ELIKAHLPDVALLDYRM,RYMKYLTGCAKLFRQGY,TGRVPLDQMSWVTPARW,IVKAVLDCAKGRDVVAP,QTRFANAPIRWLHADIM,GYRPDPATGAVNVPIYA'
    form = Pep_str_Des(initial={'Input_peptide': Input_peptide})

return render(request, 'Structure_Descriptor/Des.html', {'form':form})
```

error:

```
IOError at /Pep_Str_Des/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/pep_web/Structure_Descriptor/Input.csv'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://93.188.167.63:8080/pep_learn/Pep_Str_Des/
Django Version: 1.10.8
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/pep_web/Structure_Descriptor/Input.csv'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in _get_handle, line 356
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/pep_web',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.8-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
Server time:    Sat, 17 Feb 2018 09:49:35 +0000
```

**This was my previous post:**
[" Errno 13 Permission denied 'bnr_code.csv'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729750/errno-13-permission-denied-bnr-code-csv/48729790?noredirect=1#comment84458810_48729790)

Comment: Well, might not be an appropriate question to start with but are you running this inside a virtual environment? Seems like the permissions are messed up.

Comment: no its not running with virtualenv

Comment: Ok Jax, Lets try this create a virtualenv, by typing "virtualenv YOURPROJECTNAME" , then source the environment "source YOURPROJECTNAME/bin/activate". Once your in the virtual environment start installing the python packages you need for the project without using sudo for example "pip install pandas"

Comment: FYI, store the files you need to access under your project, you wouldn't have to explicitly change permissions over time.. best of luck

Comment: Can you explain this "you would have to explicitly change permissions over time" little bit more I dint get it, I am a beginner :(

Comment: Was typo, updated my last comment, can you setup your project again with a virtual environment  please and store the csv under the new environment in a folder, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @TheeCodeDragon I have tried your suggestion but its not working.

Comment: Might be a permissions issue. Can you try running your server as root and see if it still occurs? If it does then it is definitely a permissions issue

Comment: @Rudresh Panchal Yes it is :(

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot I am able to solve the problem as given bellow..

First I removed all the permission from the folder...

```
chmod 000 pep_web
```

then

```
chmod -R 777 pep_web
```

worked for me like a magic..

Thanks....